# Conferir se todos os itens de uma string são diferentes?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Como posso conferir se todos os itens de uma string são diferentes ?

Por exemplo:

```
x:"abcdefga" = False
y:"abcdefg" = True
```

Já que `x[0] == x[7]`, logo seria `False`.

Mas no caso usaria essa condição em um `if`.

Existe alguma função para isso no python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por teoria dos conjuntos, uma estrutura de dados `set` não permite repetição de elementos. Portanto:

```
>>> x = "abcdefga"
>>> conjunto = set(x)
>>> conjunto
{'f', 'c', 'g', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'a'}
```

Ou seja, se a comparação de `len` for igual entre a `string` e o conjunto, não há elementos repetidos. Caso contrário (conjunto tem menos elementos), há alguma repetição:

```
len(x) == len(conjunto) # True se não há elementos repetidos. False caso contrário.
len(x) > len(conjunto) # True se há elementos repetidos. False caso contrário.
```